# Lambda query previous parameter access

Tags: c#, lambda

Is possible to access a parameter variable of a previous condition?
How to do this?

```
var result = collectionA
    .First(a => a.id == 1)
    .CollectionB
    .SelectMany(b => b.CollectionC)
    .Select(c => new { propA = a.id, propC = c.id });
```

Comment: you have to create your own class implementing Ienumerable  which also can access previous items. this will be the most efficient way otherwise using unusual, complex linq tricks would be slow and ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution based on @Artem's answer:

```
var result = CollectionA
    .Where(a => a.id == 1)
    .SelectMany(b =>
        b.CollectionB
        .SelectMany(c => c.CollectionC)
        .Select(c => new { b.id, c.id })
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```
var result = collectionA
.Where(q => q.id == 1).Take(1) //it will be collection of 1 element
.Select(a => a
.CollectionB
.SelectMany(b => b.CollectionC)
.Select(c => new { propA = a.id, propC = c.id })).First();
```

or

```
(new [] { collectionA.First(q => q.id == 1) })
.Select(a => a
....
```

or just

```
var a = collectionA.First(q => q.id = 1);
a.Select( .....
```

Comment: I will test. Thanks.

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me. I've edited my question to put the solution I used. Thanks!